# Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

Quantum queries

1. We just apply the boolean function to the computational basis labels.
2. X is an n-bit string representing an n-qubit state, then we can try $|x\rangle$ to $f(x)$. but if $f(x)$ is constant, that is not reversible and not unitary?

The solution is to copy the input and add the output to a new “scratch” qubit: $$|x\rangle|y\rangle \mapsto |x\rangle|y⊕f(x)\rangle$$
Now, before you get all “but no-cloning!” on me, remember that cloning a basis is perfectly fine.

can someone explain me how these question differentiates quantum algorithms from classical ones?

I tried like for a boolean function $x+y+x.y$, I get a nor balanced nor constant function, how it does not help me anywhere in quantum problem.

Comment: If your first question mark was a question the answer is what you say: $|x\rangle|y\rangle>\mapsto |x\rangle|y\oplus f(x)\rangle$ where $\oplus$ is addition modulo 2. This map is reversible, hence unitary. Regarding your 2nd question. In short : the [Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsch%E2%80%93Jozsa_algorithm), although of little current practical use, is one of the first examples of a quantum algorithm that is ***exponentially faster*** than any possible deterministic classical algorithm.